# Using Spring JDBCTemplate with Postgres to query ip addresses

Tags: postgresql-9.1, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I have a table that has IP Addresses (v4) stored as varchar (I Cannot change this)...

I'm trying to query for a range of IP addresses... like this:

```
select colA, colB from table where cast(ipaddress as inet) >= ?
```

and I'm passing in to my PreparedStatement:

```
"'1.1.1.1'::inet"
```

I've also tried:

```
"cast('1.1.1.1' as inet)"
```

and

```
"inet '1.1.1.1'"
```

I get an error that my type is not correct for type inet.

I've also tried to create an InetAddress for the ip address and pass that in as my arguments which gives me a whole other error.

Has anyone else had this same problem and conquered it?

Comment: do you have a valid sql statement that would run correctly under psql? how about this: select colA, colB from table where cast(ipaddress as inet) >= cast(? as inet)

Comment: I actually solved the issue... I didn't get a chance to update this withe the solution; but, what you suggested is what I ended up with.